# Access to local path denied

Tags: vb.net, api, download, filestream

I'm using Sharefile API and I'm trying to download files from Sharefile but when I do it I get the message:

> Access to path 'C:\_testing' is denied.

Here's part of the code to the download method:

```
Public Sub FileDownload(ByVal fileId As String, ByVal localPath As String)

        ...
        ...

            Try

                Dim target As FileStream = New FileStream(localPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
                Dim chunk(8192) As Byte
                Dim len As Integer

                ...
         ...
         ...

    End Sub
```

At the line where I define "target" it throws an exception and the message is the one posted above the code sample.

Why is this? My test folder has read/write permissions and FileMode is set to "Create". Also, I've tried in different locations and without any luck.

Comment: Does 'C:_testing' exist ? Seems weird, may be 'C:\testing'. Plus you must specify a filename, like 'C:\testing\mytest.whatever'

Comment: @Arty, yes it does. I edited my post and now 'C:\\_testing' is shown. As I said, I tried many different folders, all existent

Comment: As i said, you want to download a FILE not a FOLDER. Whatever you folder is, you want to specify a filename, for example 'C:\_testing\thefileIwant.jpg'

Comment: No man, as I stated in the question's title, the folder is local, the folder is in my machine and that's the destination for the file. Did you understand? Or do I need to write in capital letters too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many comments, i'll try to post an answer.

```
Dim target As FileStream = New FileStream(localPath & fileId, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
```

You want to download a FILE, not a FOLDER.

For instance,

```
Dim target As FileStream = New FileStream("C:\Users\Me\Desktop", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
```

throws an error,

```
Dim target As FileStream = New FileStream("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
```

doesn't.

Comment: Check the comment to your comment above

Comment: Dude, I know it's the destination folder, but you have to specify the name of the file for a FileStream. Not FolderStream, FileStream... I posted an answer, just give it a try. You're welcome.

Comment: I know that. Anyway, with your help, I think I found the problem. It may be the parameter being passed that's not correct. As you said, it may be path without the filename and that returns an error. I'll check it soon, thanks

Comment: Well, that was it. No need to change any code, just pass the right parameter. Thanks! I'll mark as answered